# FB UI; I Can't post dialog without 'Say something about this'

Tags: javascript, facebook, dialog, feed, facebook-feed

I am having trouble with FB UI and its JavaScript SDK feed dialog.
I Can't post on wall message with an empty *'Say something about this'* field. I receive a success response after my send, but the message is not displayed on the wall. If I write something in that field, the dialog will be displayed. How to fix this?

I send the dialog like this:

```
FB.ui(
    {
        method: 'feed',
        name: 'example',
        link: loc,
        picture: src,
        description:description,
        message: 'example',
        actions: {"name":"example", "link": loc},
    },
```

Comment: Check if the post shows up in your activity log. If it does, then nothing went wrong – Facebook has just decided not to display it anywhere else, because their algorithms think it might not be that relevant, if it doesn’t contain a message written by the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can´t prefill the message field, and it is not allowed to prefill anyway. You must read the platform policy before creating any App: https://developers.facebook.com/policy/

As you can read in the docs, there is no message parameter anyway: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/v2.4#params

That being said, if it does not show up on the wall, check your activity log as CBroe commented.